# How to handle error on img tag in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

getting a url undefined error on the img tag below, most of the links being passed to src work as they are coming from the spotify api, but I guess even some of the sources the spotify api proves are broken, so how do I handle the img tag for broken links as currently I get a 'url is undefined' error

```
                <GridList cellHeight={130} style= {{margin:0}} className="gridList" cols={2}>
                    {
                        this.state.fixedArtist.map((artist, index) => (
                            <GridListTile key={index}>
                                <a className="rank-song-label" key={index} href={artist.uri} >
                                        <img src={artist.images[0].url} className="rank-album-cover" alt="Album Cover" />
                                    
                                        <span className="rank-song_name"> {artist.name}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </GridListTile>

                        ))
                    }
                </GridList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to hide img tag if no image URL is available  then you can do below,

```
<GridList cellHeight={130} style= {{margin:0}} className="gridList" cols={2}>
                    {
                        this.state.fixedArtist.map((artist, index) => (
                            <GridListTile key={index}>
                                <a className="rank-song-label" key={index} href={artist.uri} >
                                  {artist.images && <img src={artist.images[0].url} className="rank-album-cover" alt="Album Cover" />}
                                    
                                        <span className="rank-song_name"> {artist.name}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </GridListTile>

                        ))
                    }
                </GridList>
```

if you want to assign empty src or default url

```
 <GridList cellHeight={130} style= {{margin:0}} className="gridList" cols={2}>
                        {
                            this.state.fixedArtist.map((artist, index) => (
                                <GridListTile key={index}>
                                    <a className="rank-song-label" key={index} href={artist.uri} >
                                      {artist.images && <img src={artist.images.length>0?artist.images[0].url:'image not available url'} className="rank-album-cover" alt="Album Cover" />}
                                        
                                            <span className="rank-song_name"> {artist.name}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </GridListTile>
    
                            ))
                        }
                    </GridList>
```